# What are different anti-seize compounds used for?

Tags: anti-seize

I'm looking at buying some anti-seize compound in a little more bulk than a 1oz tube. The ones I've been looking at come with a brush. A brush as well as coming in 8oz sizes means less waste (direct application), easier to apply, and a lot less messy. One of the things I've ran into while looking, though, is they come as different compounds.

There is (from [one manufacturer](http://www.antiseize.com/slickon-bolt-dip-and-brush-2)):

- aluminum plate
- non-metallic marine grade
- nickel-graf
- moly plate
- copper plate
- nickel plate

What are each of these used for and how do they differ? Are there other bases besides what I have listed? If so, what are they used for?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While I have no indication about the specific products I will try to explain different types of anti-seize compounds.

- Molybdenum-sulfide forms a great grease, but it is not suited for high temperature applications with nickel-based alloys (AFAIK nickel is contained in most stainless steels and high strength steels): The compound breaks down in molybdenum and sulfide, sulfide attacks the metal, inducing stress corrosion cracking and cold welding. Suited for up to 300°C.
- Teflon based anti seize breaks down on high temperatures forming corrosive fluoride compounds. Offers also a good lubrication, depending on the product it could be food compatible. Great chemical resistance.
- Copper based anti seize is to be avoided in combination with aluminum parts. Copper induces galvanic corrosion on the aluminum. Suited for up to 1100°C. Since copper is a toxic metal you should avoid skin contact.
- Nickel based anti seize is toxic. Finely powdered nickel is not something you want on your skin. Nickel causes severe allergies and other problems. Offers protection for up to 1400°C.
- Aluminum based anti seize should be compatible with aluminum applications. Good for up to 1100°C. Drawback: There is again that problem with that finely powdered metal everywhere (your tools, workplace, skin etc.).
- Ceramic based anti seize (My favorite). Since it is metal-free galvanic corrosion is no problem, it offers highest temperature resistance and should be virtually chemically inert. Depending on the product it could be even food compatible.

TLDR: For automotive applications I would choose the ceramic anti seize.

Comment: I've used copper anti-seize on aluminium, Do'h. I use a ceramic brake grease for caliper slide pins, is there any situation where using this ceramic grease would cause problems? I am more concerned about bolts coming loose over time with ceramic over copper.

Comment: @DizzyFool perhaps you want to take this into chat? When to apply different types of compounds is a large and complicated field. Sometimes you need anti-seize. Sometimes you need a very specific type of grease. Some areas of certain things should never come in contact with grease or anti-seize. Please also keep in mind that anti-seize and grease are different things

Comment: What about zinc anti-seize? Seems like the perfect metal for everything < 750°F !!!

Comment: Is Ceramic based anti seize OK on brass parts (working on a gas range burner)?

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica in general brass should not need anti-seize as it is self-lubricating (within limits). While I don't know your specific application my gut feeling tells me that when you need anti-seize on standard brass items there is something else wrong.

Comment: @Martin Thanks! I cannot speak to whether Bosch made a design error. It is a common issue across Thermador and other gas ranges that these venturi tubes seize and need to be drilled out. This is the part that siezes: https://www.appliancepartspros.com/bosch-venturi-tube-189023-ap2825260.html  Here you can see folks (including me) drill out the tube: https://youtu.be/p5O7UV_aQjw?t=27 https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/55443/14675

Comment: @DizzyFool I have a bottle of Permatex copper anti-seize that specifically lists aluminum as a compatible metal. Some light searching suggests that copper anti-seize should be avoided not be used with aluminum if an electrical current is applied directly (although Permatex recommends copper anti-seize for use with spark plug threads).

Answer (score -1):

The industry ( repair manuals etc.) advise to use nonpetroleum base lubricants for break hardware. The main thing to remember; any metal to metal parts need an anti seize lube,or moly(synthetic). Rubber to metal parts,such as caliper pins which engage rubber boots & seals need silicone past such as caliper grease.Check out mechanics,who repair vehicles for a living,also,such as Eric the car guy,South Main auto etc. found on youtube.

Comment: There are many seriously qualified and knowledgeable mechanics and technicians on here...