# Can I use Ceramic Extreme Lubricant as I would Aluminum/Nickel Anti-Seize?

Tags: tools, anti-seize

I would like to buy a tub of Anti-Seize. I'd like to make sure that it's has a wide possibility of uses.

I already have a tub/bottle of [Permatex 24125 Ceramic Extreme Brake Parts Lubricant](https://smile.amazon.com/Permatex-24125-Ceramic-Extreme-Lubricant/dp/B0018PSASU/ref=pd_sim_263_4?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B0018PSASU&pd_rd_r=5XVQJF3W232VVSZNMTYZ&pd_rd_w=OXRWc&pd_rd_wg=jP2tW&psc=1&refRID=5XVQJF3W232VVSZNMTYZ). Can this be used for stuff like lug nuts and rotor-hat faces where one would use Nickel/Aluminum Anti-seize?

Does Permatex have a material-agnostic/Ceramic solution? Does anyone have a suggestion as to which product will fit my needs best? Is there a one Anti-Seize to rule them all?

Thank you for your time.

PS: I've read the post about the different kinds of Anti-Seize.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a link to the post you refer to...

Comment: [If this is the post you are talking about](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/41976/4152), I think it's already been answered in the last part of the post.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I don't see any mention of brand and/or product SKU, though. When I google it I don't find common trusted brands like CRC, Permatex, etc. I can only find one product; Walter Rock n' Roll. finding a product only made by one company concerns me. Also, the linked post doesn't explain if Brake Lube and Anti-Seize are interchangeable. I guess this could work better in SE.Chemistry, but I feel it makes sense here.

Comment: @NitrusInc if you want a CRC ceramic anti-seize: http://www.crcind.com/crc/CRCproductdetail.csp?division=automotive&product=CERAMIC%20PASTE

Comment: @Myself Thank you! I don't understand why that refused to come up when I googled it. Even when I Google "CRC Ceramic Anti-Seize" it doesn't show up until the last few results on the first page. Odd. It also looks like a spray rather than a paste? Seems like it might be an issue using it near brake parts?

Comment: Perhaps it is a spray: The ceramic particles are in a solvent suspension, the solvent then evaporates leaving behind the particles and some sticky stuff.

Comment: Ofc you do not want to spray it onto the rotor or the friction surface. You just spray it onto the lug bolts, the bare hub and the back of the pads.

Comment: @Myself Aye. It looks like it's more of a Construction/Industrial-use product rather than Automotive. I'll look into it a bit more, though. Thank you.