# How to take care of bolted joints

Tags: bolts

My cargo van (Ford E-250 2007, in case it matters) has the brackets of the stabilizer bar (let me abbreviate with "sb") directly bolted to the frame.  I have to change the bushings of the sb, and that requires me to take those bolts out.  What scares me is that there's no nut in this joint; the thread where the bolt goes is made directly in the frame.  So, if I mess up with that thread, I'm messing up with nothing less than the whole vehicle's frame.  In this concern, all the service manual specifies is the torque to apply when fastening, and to not reuse the bolts (without specifying the grade of the replacement bolts).
I'm afraid that there are several other parts that are bolted directly to the frame, like the exhaust and the fuel tank.

Hence, my question is: what can I do every time I loosen and tighten bolts to better preserve the threads on the frame?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a product: [Anti-Seize Compound](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002YLBBHY)

[image]

Anti-Seize will:

- Protect the threads
- Prevent any galling
- Help prevent corrosion

There are many different types/brands of anti-seize. What I have listed above is a good all-around type, but you'll have to work out what is best for you. [This thread](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/41968/4152) may help you decide.

As Mike said in his answer, to have the absolutely correct bolts, go to the dealership to buy an *exact* replacement. On the other hand, a high quality bolt from Fastenal or even a big box home improvement store of the correct grade (SAE - Grade 8; Metric - 10.9 or higher) will get the job done without issue, usually for a lot cheaper. Just ensure you get one which is the same thread pitch, the same basic length, and has a head which is big enough to support what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct replacement bolts, of the correct grade, will be available from the dealer.

Use some protective compound / grease and the new ones will go in fine using correct quality tools.